# What is the Virtual Directory in Visual Studio while using IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use the IIS instead of VS's `IIS Express` to run and debug my application but while enabling it in the project settings i am unable to set `Project URL` field tried possible paths *for e.g. localhost, project folder, IIS web physical path etc.* but none of them worked.

Also the `Create Virtual Directory` button doesn't work says cant create virtual directory.

Please help i need to debug this app on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio with an Administrator privileges.